# Why extjs script crash IE9?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a simple script and use extjs 4.1.1:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css">
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script>
            Ext.onReady(function() {
                Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    layout: {
                        type: 'table',
                        columns: 2
                    },
                    defaults: {
                        frame: true,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200
                    },
                    items: [test()]
                })
            })

            function test() {
                return Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
                    title: null,
                    rowspan: 2,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 200,
                    activeTab: 0,
                    items: [{
                        name: 'test',
                        title: 'test'
                    }]
                })

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

This script crash IE9. Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`createWidget`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-createWidget) is deprecated in Ext4. Use Ext.create or Ext.widget instead.

```
return Ext.widget('tabpanel', {
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is fiddle for it :    http://jsfiddle.net/webfriend13/n2qyL/

```
  return Ext.widget('tabpanel', {
```

As A1rPun pointed out, createWidget is deprecated in Ext4. Use Ext.create or Ext.widget instead.